# How do stdio functions handle partial successes?

Tags: c

If I do

```
int res = puts("hello world");
```

and an error occurs after writing `"hello"` will it return `EOF` or 5?

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/puts.html doesn't appear to be very clear on this.

Apparently http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html
does handle partial successes (though I imagine there must be some information loss if `size!=1`), but what about the rest of the `stdio` family?

Comment: looks completely clear to me.

Comment: *How do stdio functions handle partial successes?*  In short, poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a partial success is a write error. So the function returns `EOF`.

Chapter 7.19.7.10-3 in C99 specs clearly say:

> ## Returns
>
> The puts function returns EOF if a write error occurs; otherwise it returns a nonnegative value.

Answer (score 4):

From the POSIX reference you link to for `puts`:

> Upon successful completion, *puts()* shall return a non-negative number. Otherwise, it shall return EOF, shall set an error indicator for the stream, and *errno* shall be set to indicate the error.

That says it very clearly: If there is an error, anywhere or anytime, during the output then `EOF` will be returned and `errno` will be set appropriately. The [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) function only returns with a success if all the output was sent to the output stream successfully.

As for other functions, they contain similar notes that say what happens when they succeed or fail. If a function can *partially* succeed, like [the `fwrite` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) it will say something to that effect:

> The number of objects written successfully, which may be less than count if an error occurs.

Comment: *The number of objects written successfully, which may be less than count if an error occurs.*  Interesting to note:  the return value won't tell you if an object gets partially written.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's true. If `fwrite` manages to write two and a half objects, before there's an error, it will return `2`.